# Listando as querys mais ofensoras no MySQL

Tags: mysql, query

Gostaria de saber quais são as queries mais ofensoras na minha base de dados.

Eu já utilizei os métodos convencionais "Show full processlist" e entre outros.

Comment: ofensoras? Desculpe, não estou familiarizado com o termo, o que isto quer dizer?

Comment: Também não estou familiarizado com o termo @GuilhermeNascimento, mas acho que ele quis dizer mais "pesadas", que consomem mais recursos de processamento e etc...

Answer (score 4):

> Você pode fazer o uso da query abaixo:

```
select * from sys.`x$statement_analysis`
```

Ela vai trazer diversas informações sobre qual a query mais executada, latência, latência média, número de vezes em que ela foi executada, linhas afetadas, dentre um monte de outras informações.

> Lembrando que o servidor MySQL tem que estar configurado para analisar esses dados.

Para habilitar no MySQL Server edite o arquivo my.cnf e verifique se as configurações estão como descrito abaixo:

```
performance_schema_consumer_events_statements_history_long=ON
performance_schema_consumer_events_statements_history=ON
performance_schema_consumer_events_stages_current=ON
performance_schema_consumer_events_stages_history=ON
performance_schema_consumer_events_stages_history_long=ON
performance_schema_consumer_events_waits_current=ON
performance_schema_consumer_events_waits_history=ON
performance_schema_consumer_events_waits_history_long=ON

performance_schema=ON

performance_schema_instrument='%=ON'
```

Fonte: https://runops.wordpress.com/2015/08/12/mysql-performance-schema/

Comment: Apenas como referência:  https://runops.wordpress.com/2015/08/12/mysql-performance-schema/ (link em inglês)

Comment: Leonan, na realidade eu peguei essa query no proprio workbench na área de performance analitics.

Comment: o artigo é só pra complementar. Se tiver um tempo dá uma complementada de como se faz para ativar, nem todo server ver com essa opção habilitada. Principalmente hospedagens de site.

Comment: Aah sim obrigado :) achei que tinha dito que achei lá kkk